# TS 4.1 dropped the Position interface from lib.dom.d.ts. How should I change code that uses Position?

Tags: typescript

I have some TypeScript code that uses the `Position` interface from `lib.dom.d.ts`.
I'm working to migrate to TS 4.1, in which the definition of `Position` has been removed.

What should I be using instead now?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the interface was renamed to `GeolocationPosition` in [16031bc Update LKG](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/commit/16031bc429305e5daabf263f208678a6729a161e) on 10 Jan 2021.

This mirrors an [earlier change](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-DOM-lib-generator/commit/115267e6573338806cf041791b66a9adb9226cb7#r45632186) to the underlying IDL files that generate this.

Comment: Thanks. That was what I was looking for.